# How can I fix Flask in local appengine env giving 404/500 error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm running into a 404 error (in the console) and 500 error (in the browser) when I'm simply trying to run this AppEngine tutorial

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env

I followed the whole tutorial, copying the latest files from github, and am trying to run it in the local env.

```
dev_appserver.py --port=8080 --enable_console=yes app.yaml
```

When I try to browse to http://localhost:8080

In the console, I get

```
HTTPError()
HTTPError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib
\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib
\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib
\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 292, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\devappserver2\request_rewriter.py", line 314, in _rewriter_m
iddleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\request_handler.py", line 165,
in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\request_handler.py", line 308,
in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 97, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 331, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 136, in CheckSuccess
    self._traceback)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 161, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 223, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 248, in _MakeRealSyncCall

    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 485, in Send
    self._Authenticate()
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 631, in _Authenticate
    super(HttpRpcServer, self)._Authenticate()
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 369, in _Authenticate
    auth_token = self._GetAuthToken(credentials[0], credentials[1])
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 308, in _GetAuthToken
    response = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
INFO     2019-04-18 09:56:39,905 module.py:861] default: "GET /form HTTP/1.1" 50
0 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib
\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib
\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib
\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 292, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\devappserver2\request_rewriter.py", line 314, in _rewriter_m
iddleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\request_handler.py", line 165,
in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\request_handler.py", line 308,
in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 97, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 331, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 136, in CheckSuccess
    self._traceback)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 161, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 223, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 248, in _MakeRealSyncCall

    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 485, in Send
    self._Authenticate()
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 631, in _Authenticate
    super(HttpRpcServer, self)._Authenticate()
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 369, in _Authenticate
    auth_token = self._GetAuthToken(credentials[0], credentials[1])
  File "C:\googlecloudsdk\install\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\goo
gle\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 308, in _GetAuthToken
    response = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

In the browser, I get

```
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I've found some posts with similar symptoms, but not exact. And none of the solutions suggested fix the issue.

Tried:
- Specifying the port 8080 in the dev_appserver.
- Ensuring ASP.NET framework was installed.
- Turning on IIS.
- Ensuring SDK is latest version.

This is also just straight from Google's tutorial.

Anybody have any insight/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found INFO     2019-04-18 09:56:39,905
>   module.py:861] default: "**GET /form** HTTP/1.1" 500

this line jumps out. Are you sure you followed step 2 [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env#setting_up_jinja2_templates) and step 4 [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env#creating_a_request_handler_for_your_flask_app)?

If you are, can you run the command below in the project directory and provide the output? (Don't forget to remove [PII/SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data))

`dir . /s /b sortorder:N`

Comment: Yes, I created the templates in the /templates directory.
[Project file tree](https://github.com/kroger-media/appengine-flask-tutorial/blob/master/project-tree.txt)

[main.py](https://github.com/kroger-media/appengine-flask-tutorial/blob/master/main.py). If I give main.py a nonsense path to the template, it very clearly complains about the missing file, so I have to assume it's able to find it when the path is proper.